# AngularJS | Handling $broadcast & $on for specific instance of the same controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a utility controller build to manage documents attachments for reusing across my application.

```
<div ng-controller="someController">
    <div ng-controller="documentController as temp1"></div>
    <div ng-controller="documentController as temp2"></div>
</div>
```

Under the parent controller i.e. `someController` I have a broadcast method..

```
var module = angular.module("MyModule");
module.controller("someController",
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.$broadcast("callSomeFunctionInDocumentsController");
    });

module.controller("documentController",
    function($scope) {
        $scope.$on("callSomeFunctionInDocumentsController", function() {
            //do something here
        });
    });
```

Now the problem I am facing is that since the `documentController` is added twice to the view, the $on method is executed twice as well. Whereas based on some condition I would want to call the $on method either in `temp1` or `temp2` instance and not both.

I am not sure if what I wish to achieve is possible but any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `$broadcast` works simply: *everyone who registered is notified through* `$on`.

In your example, both controllers are registered.

So why do you use the same controller twice? Maybe worth to switch to [component](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)?

---

What about this one:

```
<div ng-controller="someController">
    <div ng-controller="documentController as temp1"></div>
    <div ng-if="oneCtrlGotNotification" ng-controller="documentController as temp2"></div>
</div>
```

where `oneCtrlGotNotification` is some flag (maybe under `$rootScope`).

So you will display second controller only when 1st already notified.

But it is a workaround.

Comment: Much appreciated, Maxim. I guess the ng-if solution, being a workaround still works. Will also look into the component part. Stay safe and take care.

Comment: @KshitijThube you welcome to upvote and accept if this response was helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to give a unique id to each element with a controller:

```
<div ng-controller="someController">
    <div id="temp1" ng-controller="documentController as temp1"></div>
    <div id="temp2" ng-controller="documentController as temp2"></div>
</div>
```

Then use the `$attrs` local to differentiate:

```
app.controller("documentController", function($scope, $attrs) {
    $scope.$on("callSomeFunctionInDocumentsController", function() {
        if ($attrs.id == "temp1") {
           //do something specific to "temp1" controller
        });
    });
})
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-)
- [AngularJS $attrs Type API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes)

Comment: In my broadcast method, how how do I select which ID to broadcast the event to?

Comment: All listeners listening for name event on this scope get notified. Afterwards, the event propagates to all direct and indirect scopes of the current scope and calls all registered listeners along the way. The event cannot be canceled. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope Event Propagation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-events-propagation).